# SwiftUI is complaining Type of expression is ambiguous without more context in navigationBarItems leading

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm just placing some views in navigationBarItems, leading property. but Xcode keep complaining "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" in my first Text element:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(people) {person in
                PersonView(person: person)
            }
        }.navigationBarItems(leading: VStack {
                HStack(spacing: 100) {
                    Text("Find People").font(.system(size: 30)).bold()
                    Text("Follow All").foregroundColor(Color(ColorUtils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: Constants.THEME.THEME_COLOR)))
                }
                HStack(spacing: 100) {
                     Text("Import from: ")
                     ForEach(socialIcons, id: \.self) {icon in
                         Image(icon).resizable().frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                     }
                }
            },
            trailing: nil
        )
    }
}
```

This is what I wanna achieve
[image]

This is my snapshot of the code:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Don't Trust Xcode:

Xcode is [not very intelligent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVak7.png) to tell you what is the real issue in SwiftUI enough (yet). So believing or not, the issue is with the `trailing: nil`.

You should get rid of it!

So it would be:

```
    .navigationBarItems(leading: VStack {
        HStack(spacing: 100) {
            Text("Find People").font(.system(size: 30)).bold()
            Text("Follow All").foregroundColor(Color(ColorUtils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: Constants.THEME.THEME_COLOR)))
        }
        HStack(spacing: 100) {
            Text("Import from: ")
            ForEach(socialIcons, id: \.self) {icon in
                Image(icon).resizable().frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            }
        }
    }) /* `trailing: nil` removed */
```