# VStack error when I initiate a TextField using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, textfield, swiftui

There are no errors until I create this `TextField`.

Also, there are no errors if I create a `TextField("Placeholder", text: .constant(""))` like this.

I am trying to use the data from the TextField which is of type Int.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var answer: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text("some text")
            Spacer()
            TextField($answer)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is with the `TextField` and it actually:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'TextField<_>' with an argument list of type '(Binding)'

To fix that, You need to first provide a `title` and the label of the binding argument: `text`:

```
TextField("This can be an empty string", text: $answerString)
```

And note that `TextField` can not accept a number as the binding argument alone! You must also provide a `Formatter` to make it working:

```
TextField("", value: $answer, formatter: NumberFormatter())
```

Also as I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59078282/5623035), you should not trust Xcode error reasons, Specially when you are working with SwiftUI.